# Meaning of 一軒 in context

Tags: translation, meaning, manga

This is from the manga 「腐女子交流記 ～アラサー×JK～ 」, a 4-koma about the life of female otaku. On this page two colleagues are discussing how it’s not easy to be an otaku when one is no longer young and friends get busy with life and family.

[image: fragment of page 161 from volume 2]

> コス香 「好きなだけやればいいってのはわかってるんですけど」
>
> コス香 「私…いつまでコスプレできるんでしょうか…」だばー
>
> オタ子「悲しい話になってきたわね…」
>
> オタ子 「このまま**一軒**どう？」ぐすっ
>
> コス香「お伴します」

I know that `一軒` means “one house/home” but not sure if here it’s used in literal sense or something metaphorical. Is Otako offering Kosuka to move in together? BTW she’s living alone in a rental apartment (マンション).

Incidentally, the page is titled 「上を向いて歩こう」 but this seems to just refer to them both crying and not  related (?) to the line in question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Otako is saying "how about a drink?" 一軒 refers to one izakaya/pub. "一軒どう?" and "一杯どう?" almost always mean this.

Comment: Yeah, this 軒 is often used when talking about going from club to club or when bar-hopping. 「もう一軒行こう！」'Let's go to another club/bar!'